# Queue SLURM jobs to run X minutes after each other

Tags: slurm

I have been trying to search around for an *example* of how to use the following option for job dependencies, `-d, --dependency=<dependency_list>`.

In the documentation, the syntax is shown to be `after:job_id[[+time][:jobid[+time]...]]`
But I am unable to find any examples of this, and to be honest I find the presentation of the syntax confusing.

I have tried `sbatch --dependency=after:123456[+5] myjob.slurm` and `sbatch --dependency=after:123456+5 myjob.slurm`, but this yields the error

`sbatch: error: Batch job submission failed: Job dependency problem`.

How can I add a dependency to `Job B` so that it starts X minutes after `Job A` starts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With guidance from damienfrancois to exclude the brackets, I tried the following

`sbatch --dependency=after:123456:+5 myjob.slurm`

Which seems to work beautifully, listing it in the queue as dependent.

EDIT: This is for version `19.05.07`

Answer (score 5):

The square brackets `[...]` indicate an optional parameter value and should not appear in the actual parameter value. Try with

```
sbatch --dependency=after:123456+5 myjob.slurm
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to include in the original post that I tried that as well. The line above (without the trailing comma) yields the error `sbatch: error: Batch job submission failed: Job dependency problem`

Comment: Then you probably have a too old version of Slurm installed on the cluster you are using. You can find out with `scontrol version`. I believe this feature was introduced in 20.02.

Comment: That makes sense, it seems my cluster is running version `19.05.07`