# Chain multiple SLURM jobs with dependency

Tags: slurm, sbatch

In a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64497802/queue-slurm-jobs-to-run-x-minutes-after-each-other) I asked how to queue a job B to start after job A, which is done with

`sbatch --dependency=after:123456:+5 jobB.slurm`

where `123456` is the id for job A, and `:+5` denotes that it will start five minutes after job A.
I now need to do this for several jobs. Job B should depend on job A, job C on B, job D on C.

`sbatch jobA.slurm` will return `Submitted batch job 123456`, and I will need to pass the job id to the call with dependency for all but the first job. As I am using a busy cluster, I can't rely on incrementing the job ids by one, as someone might queue a job between.

As such I want to write a script that takes the job scripts `(*.slurm`) I want to run as arguments, e.g.

`./run_jobs.sh jobA.slurm jobB.slurm jobC.slurm jobD.slurm`

The script should then run, for all jobs scripts passed to it,

```
sbatch jobA.slurm # Submitted batch job 123456
sbatch --dependency=after:123456:+5 jobB.slurm # Submitted batch job 123457
sbatch --dependency=after:123457:+5 jobC.slurm # Submitted batch job 123458
sbatch --dependency=after:123458:+5 jobD.slurm # Submitted batch job 123459
```

What is an optimal way to do this with bash?

Comment: What is the nature of the dependency? And how similar are the job scripts? Just because, depending on the answers to those questions, the goal might be more easily achieved by simply putting `sbatch <next script>` at the end of each script or similar.

Comment: That would be a solution, but I need them to be spaced apart in time by ~ 5 minutes, which would not be the case if I were to invoke `jobB` from `jobA`. To answer your question, I can not have two jobs starting at the same time, as that will lead them to fail (with no option to ameliorate that condition).

Comment: Would inserting a `sleep 300` in the submission script at the beginning or the end would be practical? If so, you can do as suggested, or submit them all with the same job name and the `--dependency=singleton` option

Comment: `dependency=singleton` would not be feasible, as I want the jobs to run in parallell, as some may take several days to complete.

Comment: As for `sleep` for delayed submission, the jobs are placed into queue, and will sometimes start at the same time even though they were submitted apart from each other in time.

Comment: OK, so job B needs to start >= 5 mins after job A starts or else they fail. Why does this cause them to fail? Is it something to do with restrictions of the workload manager? Or something to do with concurrent read of the input data? Or something else? Just because, understanding that will help to come up with a suitable solution.

Comment: The exact reason is difficult to explain, but I tried to find a solution that would allow two jobs to start at the same time without luck. Five minutes is probably excessive, two would be just fine.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the `--parsable` option to get the jobid of the previously submitted job:

```
#!/bin/bash

ID=$(sbatch --parsable $1)
shift 
for script in "$@"; do
  ID=$(sbatch --parsable --dependency=after:${ID}:+5 $script)
done
```

Comment: This seems to work beautifully, and is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!